# EFCore unable to remove many-to-many relation in memory sqlite, but works in production sql

Tags: c#, unit-testing, many-to-many, in-memory-database, ef-core-2.1

I am trying to create a releational database using EFCore code first. I have successfully created it after some ondelete issues. 
I then thought I was in the clear to create unit tests, but the examples I had run with in an actual implementation of the database didn't work with inmemory providers(EFCore and Sqlite).

The relations are as follows: 
A, B, C are entities
A1-*B has a many to one relation 
BC Is a many to many relation
AC Is the other many to many relation.

And when I try to remove anything while in memory, it throws errors similar to the follwing where I tried to remove a entry from the B col.

```
'The property 'AId' on entity type 'AC' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges' then associate the dependent with the new principal.'
```

I tried in memory EFCore straight up but learned that it does not model relational databases, so I tried sqlite in memory. 
The following code works on a sql server.(excluding the sqlite parts)

```
using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DBContext>()
                   .UseSqlite(connection)
                   .Options;
                using (var _context = new DBContext(options))
                {
                    SeedData(_context);
                    _context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                    _context.Bs.Remove(_context.Bs.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == 1));

                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

But throws the before mentioned error.

This is the relational model in fluentapi

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<A>(pa =>
            {
                pa.HasKey(key => new { key.Id });
                pa.HasAlternateKey(key => new { key.Id, key.ExternalUID, key.InstitutionID });
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<B>(sa =>
            {
                sa.HasKey(key => new { key.Id });
                sa.HasOne(o => o.A)
                    .WithMany(s => s.Bs)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                    .HasForeignKey(k => k.AId);
                sa.HasAlternateKey(key => new { key.Id, key.AId });
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<C>(l =>
            {
                l.HasKey(key => new { key.Id });

            });



            modelBuilder.Entity<AC>(al =>
            {
                al.HasKey(key => new { key.AId, key.CId });
                al.HasOne(sa => sa.A)
                    .WithMany(s => s.ACs)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.AId);
                al.HasOne(sa => sa.C)
                    .WithMany(s => s.ACs)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .HasForeignKey(o => o.CId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<BC>(sal =>
            {
                sal.HasKey(key => new { key.BId, key.CId});                    
                sal.HasOne(sa => sa.B)
                    .WithMany(s => s.BCs)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .HasForeignKey(s => s.BId);
                sal.HasOne(sa => sa.C)
                    .WithMany(s => s.BCs)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .HasForeignKey(o => o.CId);
            });
```

After changing to sqlite in memory I expected to get a relational database that mirrored what I experience with the real database. 
IE. Deleting entities in the graph and having it only cascade to the relational entries (BC AC) and not touch the primary Entity (Such as A, B, C). 
As in the example where I am trying to delete B but for some reason it wants to modify A.

I would like if you could help me figure out what I am doing wrong, or point me in the direction of a work around for unit testing.

Comment: What if you remove `sa.HasAlternateKey(key => new { key.Id, key.AId });`? In general unique indexes/constraints including the PK which is unique itself are useless.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @IvanStoev . I tried to remove all the alternate keys from the equation both for the A and B relation. At first only for the B relation and then for both. The error persisted in memory but as before the "prod" version worked as I expected.